# Django on Pycharm community edition seems to show false-positive error message

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm new to Django and I'm using Pycharm Community 2018.1 to do my project.

While I was doing the first tutorial where you set up a model and corresponding admin page, Pycharm keeps showing this reference error which is perfectly fine when you look at the directory and the structure.

Is this what I get for using free Pycharm instead of paid Professional edition?

However, I know I'm a newb so I might be wrong here. Is it normal to get this error message in this situation?

I took a screenshot of error message(the left screen) and working Admin page(right screen) and here are my codes for `models.py` and `admin.py`

[image]

`models.py` (there is no problem with it)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals 

from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible 

# Create your models here.

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True, null = True) 
    url = models.URLField('url', unique = True) 
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

`admin.py` (you can see unresolved reference error)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from bookmark.models import Bookmark

# Register your models here.

class BookmarkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'url')

admin.site.register(Bookmark, BookmarkAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning can be solved by opening your `actual` project directory

Go to **File->Open**. Then choose your **project directory**, that is **mysite** and you are opened **pyneer_django** directory
It's nothing with the community edition